# Some issues with "read access violation"

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct  {
    char name[128], code[128];
} info;
info db[3];
info* data=db;
void find (const char *code, int size, ...) {

    bool mismatch = true;
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg,size);
    while (size-- > 0) {
        data = va_arg(arg,info*);
        printf("%s", data->code);
        if (!strcmp(data->code,code)) 
        {
            printf("%s [id:%s]\n",data->name,data->code), mismatch = false;
            }
    }
    if (mismatch) printf("No data available!");
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

    const char *spec[] = {
        "Physics of Elementary Particles",
        "Physics of Hign Energy",
        "Low-level Programming"
    };
    const char *code[] = {
        "2396","0812", "0773"
    };`enter code here`
    for (int count = 0; count < 3; ++count) {
        strncpy(db[count].name,spec[count],128);
        strncpy(db[count].code,code[count],128);
    }
    find("0812",3,db[0],db[1],db[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

After running it says "read access violation", although I hope everything is correct, it happens after function "va_arg(arg, info*)". Is it some troubles with   stack or decrypting?

Comment: When you call the function you pass e.g.  `db[0]` as argument. What is the type of `db[0]`? What is the type you try to get with `va_arg(arg,info*)`? Do those types match?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `info db[3];`?

Comment: That's the whole array, but you pass single elements to the function. What is the type of a single element in the array?

Comment: A variadic function is a peculiar way to approach the problem. What will you do when there are 1000 books?

Comment: You're passing whole arrays  but using them as pointers.  Just pass the address of each: `find("0812", 3, &db[0], &db[1], &db[2]);`

Comment: thx dudes<3 , I'm just stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function call:

```
find("0812",3,db[0],db[1],db[2]);
```

The variadic argument that you're passing in are of type `info`.  However, when you retrieve them with `va_arg` you're looking for a `info *`.  These don't match up.

You want to pass in the address of each array member.

```
find("0812",3,&db[0],&db[1],&db[2]);
```

Also, you need to call `va_end` at the bottom of `find` before you return.